# Android Ion - load image (gif) inside RecyclerView.Adapter; OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, animated-gif, android-ion

Im using Ion library to load a set of gifs inside a RecyclerView - one Gif per row.
Im using the following code to load the gif:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder vh, int i) {
    MyObject myObj = data.get(i);

    Ion.with(vh.imageViewGif)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE)
            .load(myObj.getGIF_URL());
}
```

It happens that if i keep scrolling I get the following exception (OutOfMemoryError):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:896)
>               at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:920)
>               at com.koushikdutta.ion.gif.GifDecoder.setPixels(GifDecoder.java:257)
>               at com.koushikdutta.ion.gif.GifDecoder.readImage(GifDecoder.java:504)
>               at com.koushikdutta.ion.gif.GifDecoder.nextFrame(GifDecoder.java:137)
>               at com.koushikdutta.ion.IonDrawable$IonGifDecoder$1.run(IonDrawable.java:190)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

How can i workaround this OutOfMemoryError? Any configuration on Ion is needed to handle memory and cache?

Comment: Use glide that is much good for gif.

Comment: @AnandSingh i didn't know about Glide library. I'll give it a try, looks simple and clean. Anyway, i'll leave this question open in case anyone wants to use Ion library to load Gifs.

Comment: use FrameAnimation..

Comment: Link to failing gif? It may just be too big. Multiple animated gifs per screen could also cause a lot of memory pressure.

Comment: @koush, yes, it might be the case that the gif is too big. Can i retrieve the size of what im trying to download before download?